# Refresh xaml page every x seconds and keep the current expander state

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, refresh, expander

I have a xamarin project. There is a scrollview with a list of expanders.

I like to refresh the page every x seconds, but keep the state of my expanders (isExpanded boolean).

How do I check the state of my expanders (or label, button, whatever) and keep these values during a refresh every x seconds?

I feel like I have to add a parameter to my behindcode function, similar to the 'object sender' during a tap or click event.

In the behindcode I am trying to refresh the page every x seconds with

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(x),Updatefunction);
```

Currently they all have their default isExpanded (false) state when the page refreshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a bool property in the viewModel, then binding this property to `IsExpanded="{Binding Expand1Opened}"` in `<Expander>` tab. When user click the `Expander`, IsExpanded will depend on the value of `Expand1Opened` property. no matter the refresh the page every x seconds, it will keep the current expander state. And I add `Command` for `Expander`, if `Expander` is clicked, value of `Expand1Opened` property will be changed in the ViewModel.

```
 <RefreshView IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
                     RefreshColor="Teal"
                     Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}">
            <ScrollView>
                <StackLayout>
                    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Expand1Opened}" Command="{Binding Expand1OpenedCommand}">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <Label Text="List1"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontSize="Medium" />
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <FlexLayout Direction="Row"
                            Wrap="Wrap"
                            AlignItems="Center"
                            AlignContent="Center"
                            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                            BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ColorItemTemplate}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>

                    <Expander IsExpanded="{Binding Expand2Opened}" Command="{Binding Expand2OpenedCommand}">
                    <Expander.Header>
                        <Label Text="List2"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               FontSize="Medium" />
                    </Expander.Header>
                    <Grid Padding="10">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <FlexLayout Direction="Row"
                            Wrap="Wrap"
                            AlignItems="Center"
                            AlignContent="Center"
                            BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                            BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ColorItemTemplate}" />
                    </Grid>
                </Expander>
                </StackLayout>

            </ScrollView>
        </RefreshView>
```

Here is viewModel. I have two `<Expander>`, So I add two properties `Expand1Opened` and `Expand2Opened`, and add two `Command`s called `Expand1OpenedCommand` and `Expand2OpenedCommand`, if the `<Expander>` were clicked, `Expand1OpenedCommand` will be invoked, then value of `Expand1Opened` will be changed, If the refreshview was refreshed, value of `Expand1Opened` will not be changed, so `expander`'s state wil be kept.

```
 public class MainPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        const int RefreshDuration = 2;
        int itemNumber = 1;
        readonly Random random;
        bool isRefreshing;

        public bool IsRefreshing
        {
            get { return isRefreshing; }
            set
            {
                isRefreshing = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        bool expand1Opened = false;
        public bool Expand1Opened
        {
            get { return expand1Opened; }
            set
            {
                expand1Opened = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        bool expand2Opened=false;
        public bool Expand2Opened
        {
            get { return expand2Opened; }
            set
            {
                expand2Opened = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; private set; }

        public ICommand RefreshCommand => new Command(async () => await RefreshItemsAsync());

        public ICommand Expand1OpenedCommand { get; set; }
        public ICommand Expand2OpenedCommand { get; set; }
        public MainPageViewModel()
        {
            random = new Random();
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

            Expand1OpenedCommand = new Command((() =>
            {
                expand1Opened = !expand1Opened;
            }));
            Expand2OpenedCommand = new Command((() =>
            {
                expand2Opened = !expand2Opened;
            }));


            AddItems();
        }

        void AddItems()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Items.Add(new Item
                {
                    Color = Color.FromRgb(random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255), random.Next(0, 255)),
                    Name = $"Item {itemNumber++}",
                    Isfavourite = false

                }); 
            }
        }

        async Task RefreshItemsAsync()
        {
            IsRefreshing = true;
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(RefreshDuration));
            AddItems();
            IsRefreshing = false;
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Here is running GIF.

[image]

Comment: If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the upper left corner of this answer), it will help others who have similar issue